# How can I give a 2D sketch a lateral wave?

Tags: autocad, cad, solidworks

Let me give an example on what I'm trying to mean.
[image]

I have a 2D sketch on (say) XY plane. I want to give this feature a lateral wave on XZ plane.

Here you can see I've sketched a sine curve on XY plane and have created a surface using that sketch. Now I want to give this surface a lateral wave in XZ plane.

Can anyone suggest any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to widen the initial wave, and then in the second sketch have the extents of the wave you want instead of just the line. You could do that using offsets in both directions of the line shown.

Then you can surface trim the wave with the new extents to remove the sections.

That would achieve what you want.